# Native mobile application using google dart language

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter

How to develop a native mobile applications for android using dart language ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this is possible. A Dart application can be compiled to a regular JS/HTML app and packaged as such.

For a real world example see [Veterninary Anesthesia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.damondouglas.VetAnesthesia) in the Play store.This app was written in Dart and an installable phone application version was build with PhoneGap. The developer's blog extensively details [how it was done](http://blog.damondouglas.me/2013/07/building-android-application-using-dart.html).

Native Dart apps may come eventually. There's some reports of people compiling the Dart VM on Android. Currently, the Dart team are focussing on the Web client.

Answer (score 7):

Necronomicon :)

I know this is an old post, but for those who find it... Now there is an option to create native apps for Android and iOS using Flutter. Flutter Official Website ~> https://flutter.dev/

Update[July-19]: Now you can develop app/apps for all platform(including web) with a single code base using flutter.

> Flutter is a new project to help developers build high-performance, high-fidelity, mobile apps for iOS and Android from a single codebase

By now it is in early stage, but looks very promising.

Update[September-2020]: Alfa support for Windows, MacOS and Lunix announced https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-windows-alpha-33982cd0f433

Answer (score 4):

There would be some tools like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), where you could write Dart, compile to JS, then use it to convert this whole thing to a native app. The question is if this is really worth it - I never tried it, but I could imagine that with Dart you'd need to use JS-Interop extensively, if it even works altogether - the tool might not even be able to use Dart's optimized JS output. Anyway, if you really want to do this, this might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible: as you can see in [this link](http://news.dartlang.org/2013/05/dart-project-co-founders-answer-your.html), *"the current focus for Dart is web applications"*. Or perhaps it seems a little complicated, see also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/eX2bqlMDGiU) for further info.

Answer (score 2):

Dart team is working on their own stack of dev tools from runtime to UI sdk for dart lang on mobile devices. Check this, https://www.dartlang.org/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

You can by using dart with PhoneGap or Sencha Touch

http://blog.damondouglas.me/2013/07/building-android-application-using-dart.html

http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/07/dart-and-sencha-touch-for-mobile-web.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Flutter is Google’s UI toolkit for building beautiful, natively compiled applications for mobile, web, and desktop from a single codebase.

Dart programming language is used by google.

https://flutter.dev/

Initial release date is May 2017